# How to use desert theme across all my Putty sessions?

Tags: linux, unix, putty, themes

I'm trying to follow this tutorial, titled: [Custom PuTTY Color Themes](http://www.igvita.com/2008/04/14/custom-putty-color-themes/) to have the desert theme in all my PuTTY sessions. I downloaded and ran the registry file for desert theme.

I'm now able to see the theme listed under sessions list as `igvita-desert` in my PuTTY. I loaded it and the theme is there.. But the changes are not replicated to my other putty sessions after I load them..

Should I manually replicate the colors in desert theme to my sessions to get this working?

There might be some way to do this which I'm not aware of.

Can anyone help me how can I replicate this desert theme across all my Putty sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" is that color schemes are not saved as themes you can apply to various sessions. You can only change the color scheme for each session itself.

The fastest way to get your sessions run with the new scheme:

1. Open the registry file of the desert scheme with notepad
2. Change the needed values like IP / host, username,... and don't forget to set the session title (e.g. *MyHost (Desert)*)
3. Save this as a new registry file (e.g. ssh1_desert.reg)
4. Save all sessions to the registry by double clicking on them.

It's a lot of work if you have like >20 pre-saved sessions but this is much faster than changing the colors for each session.